# How do I count the number of matches by a regex?

Tags: .net, regex

For example, I would like to count how many numbers are in a string using a regex like: [0-9]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
Regex.Matches(text, pattern).Count
```

Comment: You can also do `myRegex.Matches(text).Count`

Answer (score 6):

```
Regex.Matches(input, @"\d").Count
```

Since this is going to allocate a Match instance for each match, this may be sub-optimal performance-wise. My instinct would be to do something like the following:

```
input.Count(Char.IsDigit)
```

Comment: this will return the number of characters in a string.
"123 456" will return 6, although there are only 2 numbers.
Correct will be 
    Regex.Matches(input, @"\d+").Count

Comment: Not bad, but this is case specific. Other regex matches would not be able to be counted without having a separate function

Answer (score 3):

```
        var a = new Regex("[0-9]");
        Console.WriteLine(a.Matches("1234").Count);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 2):

.NET 7 introduced the `Count` method.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string content = @"Foxes are omnivorous mammals belonging to several genera
of the family Canidae. Foxes have a flattened skull, upright triangular ears,
a pointed, slightly upturned snout, and a long bushy tail. Foxes live on every
continent except Antarctica. By far the most common and widespread species of
fox is the red fox.";

string pattern = "fox(es)?";

int n = Regex.Count(content, pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled |
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Console.WriteLine($"There are {n} matches");
```

It has both static and instance overloads of the method.

```
var rx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled |
     RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

int n = rx.Count(content);
Console.WriteLine($"There are {n} matches");
```

Comment: This should be the way to go as of .net 7.

Answer (score 0):

The MatchCollection instance returned from a call to the Matches method on RegEx will give you the count of the number of matches.

However, what I suspect is that it might not be the count that is wrong, but you might need to be more specific with your regular expression (make it less greedy) in order to determine the specific instances of the match you want.

What you have now *should* give you all instances of a single number in a string, so are you getting a result that you believe is incorrect?  If so, can you provide the string and the regex?

Comment: sorry, worng click, posted an answer instead

Answer (score -1):

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\d+");
var input = "123 456";
Console.WriteLine(regex.Matches(input).Count); // 2
// we want to count the numbers, not the number of digits
```