# match regex character to function call

Tags: c#, regex, pushdown-automaton

I am working in C#

I want to be able to call a function on a specific character in my regular expression language and was wondering if this was possible. For example if I have my pattern as `^[0-9]*$` I would like to call the function `foo()` when a 7 is found. So if I had the string `"0129384927377"` it would call the function `foo` three times.

Any way of doing this?

If you want context I'm trying to build a *DPDA (Deterministic Pushdown Automaton)* as simply as possible and not sure the best way of doing it.

Comment: Looks very similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982213/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-matches-by-a-regex).

Comment: your regex itself is wrong..it should be what you are looking for.so it should be `7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
Regex.Matches("0129384927377","7").Count
```

Comment: And then a for loop could be used to invoke `foo()` "count" times.

Comment: For OneLiners: `Regex.Matches("0129384927377", "7").Cast<Match>().ToList().ForEach(_ => foo());`