# How to count list of matching regex in a list c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a list of I want to use regex to count in the list that contains Text 1 to Text 100.

[DOTNET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kOteF7) I created shows count = 0. I can't seem to find my mistake here.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Text 1 to Text 100
        Regex reg = new Regex(@"Text + /^(?:100|[1-9]?[0-9])$"); 
        
        int count = 0;

        // Expected to count 3
        List<string> myTexts = new List<string>() {"Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3", "Text 500"}; 
        
        foreach (var myText in myTexts)
        {
            if(reg.IsMatch(myText))
                count++;
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine($"There are {count} matches in the list");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you put `/^` in the middle of the regex? Also, spaces are meaningful. See https://dotnetfiddle.net/GJFUJ9, you need `@"Text +(?:100|[1-9]?[0-9])$"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I count the number of matches by a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982213/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-matches-by-a-regex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little change to the regex (to remove the unnecessary `" /^"` portion), you can use a little bit of `System.Linq` to get the match count:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"Text +(?:100|[1-9]?[0-9])$");

// Expected to count 3
var myTexts = new List<string> {"Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3", "Text 500"};

var count = myTexts.Count(text => reg.IsMatch(text));

// count == 3
```